# error with creating categories links ruby on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

getting an error trying to create links to my categories: 
I am getting the error...I can successfully create categories into the database and they are associated with listings...my only problem is created a link to show by category what am I doing wrong here? thanks in advance I an a newb and kinda stuck!

```
NoMethodError in ListingsController#index
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

more error:

```
Extracted source (around line #15):
13
14
15
16
17
18

      @listings = Listing.all.order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:catgeory]).id
      @listings = Listing.where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC")
    end
  end
```

my header code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Yahozzle</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><%= link_to "About", pages_about_path %> </li>
        <li><%= link_to "Contact", pages_contact_path %> </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Browse<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
            <li><%= link_to category.name, listings_path(category: category.name) %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </li>   
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <% if user_signed_in? %>


              <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Seller Account <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><%= link_to "Manage Listings", seller_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Sales History", sales_path %></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><%= current_user.name %> <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><%= link_to "Purchase History", purchases_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      <% else %>
        <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

and my controller

```
def index
    if params[:category].blank?
      @listings = Listing.all.order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:catgeory]).id
      @listings = Listing.where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC")
    end
  end
```

Comment: You have a typo - catgeory instead of category. Nothing is being found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo on line 15 - catgeory instead of category.

```
Category.find_by(name: params[:catgeory]).id
```

So the find_by returns nil, and you are calling id on that. Simply fix the typo, but even so, you should check the category exists, and maybe show a 404 if it doesn't.

Comment: crazy, I looked at that 100 times and never saw this

Comment: Yeah getting someone else to read your code, or even explaining your code to someone else, is a pretty fast way to find bugs

Comment: when an empty category is selected, it is not showing all listings but rather a blank page ...what am I missing  ?

Comment: Does at least the header show up, or is the whole page blank? Right-click on the page in your browser and Inspect Element, make sure the html is what you expected.

Comment: no everything is showing up ... just not any listings because there are none in that particular category ..if you look at my controller i tried to write an if statement to handle this...

Comment: It's hard to say really, this code doesn't include the body that iterates the listings. Keep debugging, and if you can't figure it out, post it as another question.